# hyperlink into telegram bot channel

Tags: php

I have a bot on telegram that write a message

$bot_url    = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$botToken/";
$url = $bot_url."sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($var);

Where $var=[text](https://www.google.com)

When, instead to use a generic anchor text=test I want to use $row["product_name"] that is written into the database:

$var=[$row["product_name"]](https://www.google.com)

Bot doesn't works

I tried also with ''

$var=['$row["product_name"]'](https://www.google.com)

Whats is the correct use of quotes?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes..
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE) in /...

Comment: The error means that you're likely missing a semicolon `;` or a closing curly bracket `}` on one of the lines. So fix that and use `$var=$row["product_name"];`. It should work.